# How to make sure scheduled notification works with respect to timezone and daylight savings

Tags: ios, datetime, timezone, dst, unusernotification

As far as I understand , when we pass date time components as a trigger for notification.
It automatically handles

- Change in timezone
- Change in daylight savings
- Leap year things

But I know in older UILocalnotification we've to do the below to get this above result.

```
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

Can we completely trust *UNUserNotification* with Datetimecomponents ?

Someone please clarify